# Not able to login based on the roles in katalon studion

Tags: data-driven-tests, katalon-studio

I am trying to implement a data-driven framework in Katalon Studio.

Kindly send the code to login to the application based on the roles. Login credentials are saved in an excel including roles like admin, supervisor. When I am trying to log in all users are coming through irrespective of the role.

So how to code login action based on the roles in Katalon Studio?

Comment: Post your code so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
TestData tdd = findTestData('Your Data File Object with the Excel Sheet')

int rowCount = tdd.getRowNumbers()

for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    String tdd_user = tdd.getValue(1, i)
    String tdd_password = tdd.getValue(2, i)
    String tdd_role = tdd.getValue(3, i)

    // here is the login implementation
}
```